# Is "making a hen out of a feather" really not an English expression?

Tags: expressions, popular-refrains

Today, after learning English for decades, I learned that the expression "to make a hen out of a feather" apparently is Swedish-only, and that nobody outside Sweden would understand this (other than guessing what it means).

Apparently, the English version is "to make a mountain out of a molehill". I frankly have never heard that one before, even though I've consumed insane amounts of English-language media spanning from the early 1900s to the present.

If I had said "you're making a hen out of a feather" to somebody in the USA or UK or any other native-English country, would they look at me funny and wonder what that is about?

Mountain... out of a molehill? It doesn't sound right somehow. Is there really no other variant in English which is more common?

Comment: The expression is completely unfamiliar to me (lifelong US speaker), though it is not difficult to decode its meaning. If I do a Google search for "hen out of a feather", the top results are all about the Swedish phrase. (My search history and IP geolocation do not have anything Swedish about them)

Comment: "Making a mountain out of a molehill" is a very common idiom and is really spot on. Other phrases that describe the situation are "make a big deal [out of [nothing]]" and "blow [it] out of proportion".

Comment: Once you've *made a mountain out of a molehill* you may have *raised a storm in a teacup*.

Comment: (*storm in a teacup* is rendered *tempest in a teapot* in the US) https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tempest+in+a+teapot%2Cstorm+in+a+tea+cup+%2B+storm+in+a+teacup%2Cmountain+out+of+a+mole+%2B+mountain+out+of+a+molehill&year_start=1908&year_end=2008

Comment: @MikeGraham: I'm surprised that you know what a teapot is over there !  My abiding memory of having tea made for me in the US is watching a barista put a styrofoam cup of water, with a teabag in it, into a microwave oven :-(

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark, That's a time to bring out the famous Abe Lincoln quote: "If this  is tea, please bring me coffee. If this is coffee, please bring me tea."

Comment: “Mountains out of molehills” is a common expression in Australia, but I’ve never heard of the “hens out of feathers” version. For example, in a famous twist in the TV comedy series “Kath and Kim”, Magda Szubanski’s character says Kim was making a mountain out of a molehill but then says, “The two molls in this case were...”. It’s funny because she thinks the mole in molehill is “moll” (Australian slang for “a bad girl with loose morals”, akin to outdated AmE “gangster’s moll”) playing on the idea that Australians are not very familiar with the animal “mole”.

Comment: What's the question? The one at the top, you answer in the first sentence of your explanation by saying that you learned the expression is "Swedish-only." It seems that maybe you've switched your question to if "to make a mountain out of a molehill" is a real English expression, but you answer that question yourself, too, so what is your question? Or is there no real question and this is just a diatribe about how "to make a hen out of a feather" makes sense and sounds right to you but "to make a mountain out of a molehill" doesn't and how you've somehow never heard this very common idiom.

Answer (score -1):

This saying is from the danish writer Hans Christian Andersons fairytale: "It`s perfectly true".
Its a story about how one feather becomes 5 dead hens because of gossip.